# Map returns multiple array elements for each element It iterates

Tags: javascript

instead of pushing into an empty array, I wanted to try to combine it into my variable declaration.

```
var blah = [1,2,3].map(function(x){ 
   return (x+'a'),(x+'b'),(x+'c')
});

//outcome => ['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2b', '2c', '3a', '3b', '3c']
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question?

Comment: The map function doesn't work way, the function should always return an array with the same length.

Comment: Please specify what exactly do you expect, because we have some conflicts in answers.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a way to iterate through an array and for each element it returns multiple elements. like the outcome shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and concate the items.

```js
var result = [1, 2, 3].reduce(function(r, a) {
        return r.concat(['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function (b) {
            return a + b;
        }));
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is  very clever, thanks. I guess there isn't an easy way to do so.